# Where is the edit button on the schematic circuit lab tool?

Tags: bug

If I remember right, there used to be an edit button on the schematic. The schematic html section says there is one. I can't find it, I remember it being next to the simulate this circuit link.

```
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

![schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/[not relavant].png)

<!-- End schematic -->
```

[image]

Anyway, one needs to change or the other, we shouldn't tell people something is there when it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the post, then you can edit the schematic.

That's what the reference to "preview" means — you only get a preview window while you're in the process of editing the post containing the schematic.